# Why is the running time for the sorting algorithm 0 in my program? AND the code does not works when the output is very large

Tags: c++

I tried moving "clock_t start1=clock();" as the first line for main function, it somehow works but i am measuring the running time for each sorting algorithm...
I tried using  instead clock_t but its still 0...

and I'm also quite confused the fact that when my input is 100,000, the code does not works too? I suspect its due to using 'int', so i changed it to 'double' but the problems still retained

## this is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<iomanip>
#include<chrono>
using namespace std;

void generateRandVal(int arr[],int sID){
    bool used[1000000]={false}; // to keep track of used numbers
    int count=0;

    while(count<sID){
        int num=rand()%1000000; // generate a random number in the range [0,999999]

        if (!used[num]){ // if the number hasn't been used before
            arr[count]=num;
            used[num]=true;
            count++;
        }
    }

}

void printArr(int arr[],int sID){
    for (int i=0;i<sID;i++) {
        cout<<setfill('0')<<setw(6)<<arr[i]<<" ";
        if ((i+1)%10==0)cout<<endl; // break line after every 10 elements
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int partition(int arr[],int left,int right){
    int pivot=arr[left];
    int l=left+1;
    int r=right;

    while (l<=r) {
        while(l<=r && arr[l]<=pivot)l++;
        while(l<=r && arr[r]>pivot)r--;
        if(l<r)swap(arr[l],arr[r]);
    }

    swap(arr[left],arr[r]);
    return r;
}

void quickSort(int arr[],int left,int right){
    if(left<right){
        int p = partition(arr,left,right);
        quickSort(arr,left,p-1);
        quickSort(arr,p+1,right);
    }
}

void merge(int arr[], int left, int mid, int right){
    int i,j,k;
    int n1=mid-left+1; // find starting (left)
    int n2=right-mid; // find end (right)

    // create temporary arrays
    int l[n1],r[n2];

    // copy and put data into the two temporary arrays
    for(i=0;i< n1;i++)l[i]=arr[left+i];
    for(j=0;j<n2;j++)r[j]=arr[mid+1+j];

    // merge the temporary arrays back
    i=0; // make the initial index of first subarray
    j=0; // make the initial index of second subarray
    k=left; // make the initial index of merged subarray

    while(i<n1 && j<n2){
        if(l[i]<=r[j]){
            arr[k]=l[i];
            i++;
        }else{
            arr[k]=r[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    // copy and put all the remaining elements of arry l, if still got values
    while(i<n1){
        arr[k]=l[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    // copy and put all the remaining elements of arr r, if still got values
    while(j<n2){
        arr[k]=r[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[],int left,int right){
    if(left<right){
        // find the middle
        int mid=left+(right-left)/2;

        // sorting
        mergeSort(arr,left,mid);
        mergeSort(arr,mid+1,right);

        // merging
        merge(arr,left,mid,right);
    }
}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int sID;

    cout<<"Please input the number of subscriber IDs you want (max 1000000): ";
    cin>>sID; 
    sID=min(sID,1000000); 
    //int unsortedArr[sID];
    int *unsortedArr = new int[sID]; 
    int n=sID; 

    generateRandVal(unsortedArr,sID);
    cout<<"Before sorting:\n";
    printArr(unsortedArr,sID);



    // copy and put all values from unsortedArr into mergeS_arr such that the array will only be use for merge sort
    int mergeS_arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)mergeS_arr[i]=unsortedArr[i];

//    clock_t start1=clock();
//    mergeSort(mergeS_arr,0,n-1);
//    clock_t end1=clock();
//    double mergeS_timeTaken=double(end1-start1)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC); // calculate time taken in seconds

    auto start1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    mergeSort(mergeS_arr,0,n-1);
    auto end1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto mergeS_duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end1 - start1);
    cout << "Time taken by function: " << mergeS_duration.count() << " microseconds" << endl;

    // copy and put all values from unsortedArr into quickS_arr such that the array will only be use for quick sort
    int quickS_arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)quickS_arr[i]=unsortedArr[i];

//    clock_t start2=clock();
//    quicksort(quickS_arr,0,n-1);
//    clock_t end2=clock();
//    double quickS_timeTaken=double(end2-start2)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC); // calculate time taken in seconds

    auto start2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    quickSort(quickS_arr,0,n-1);
    auto end2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto quickS_duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end2 - start2);
    cout << "Time taken by function: " << quickS_duration.count() << " microseconds" << endl;

    //cout<<mergeS_timeTaken<<" seconds for mergeS\n"<<quickS_timeTaken<<" seconds for quickS\n";

    delete[] unsortedArr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are learning C++ using an outdated approach (pre 1998).  Mainly using "C" style arrays ( 'int []') is not how C++ is used nowadyas and this kind of approach is very likely to result in buggy code, use std::vector instead.

Comment: to count numbers used use `std::map<int,int> histogram;` and histogram[number]++ to count numbers. No need to allocate a fixed size array that at some point is just going to be too small.

Comment: Please pick **one** question to ask about. I see two timings, plus the question of correctness.

Comment: `int mergeS_arr[n];` (and all similar) are not legal C++. C++ array sizes must be constants.

Comment: the `rand()` function (from C, C++ has best generators) is frequently limited to numbers between 0 and 32767. Your code may not manage more numbers.

Comment: Your input generator can take a lot of time. For instance, if you want 100,000 numbers and have generated 99,999 of them, you're repeatedly rolling a 100,000-sided die until the missing number comes up.

Comment: If I run that and input 1000, I get "Time taken by function: 88 microseconds" and "Time taken by function: 60 microseconds". Did you perhaps run some other version of the code?